# WinRT XAML - Value and text in ListBox

Tags: xaml, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml

Is there any way how to set to ListBoxItem different showing text and different hidden value. I want same thing as I can do in HTML that way:

```
<select>
    <option value="MyApple">Apple</option>
    <option value="MyOrange">Orange</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course, but that's not the way you do things with XAML. You could set a `Tag` property on your `ListBoxItem` to anything, but the common approach is to use the MVVM pattern and bindings where you would set `ItemsSource` of your `ListBox` to a collection of items and each of your items would have properties to display and other properties to use elsewhere. You would bind the visible properties to the elements in the `ItemTemplate` of your `ListBox` and bind `SelectedItem` of the `ListBox` with a `TwoWay` binding to a property of your view model. Now if you don't care about patterns and simply want to see it working - go ahead and use the `Tag` and the `SelectionChanged` event.